# Convenience sampling - Distribution forcing?

Tags: distributions, sampling, resampling

I am conducting some experiments on a data set that was collected by convenience. It is a data set based on historical data, most of which is not digitized. I know the exact distribution of the historical data but do not have the data itself. Instead I have an incomplete subset. Looking at the distribution of this subset it is completely different to the full set.

I could force my sample to have the same distribution by choosing at random a selection with the same distribution as the historical data. My question is whether or not this would be a good idea. Do I gain more by having a larger differently distributed set or a smaller matched distributed set?

Many thanks

Comment: Please clarify how you would generate a subsample with a distribution matching the historical one?

Comment: I was considering making it so that my sample had the same proportions as the total data set. For example I know a group of type A makes up 5% of the total data, I would select at random from my sample of A data so that it made up 5% of my sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the historical dataset has not been collected in an unbiased manner (or in a manner that might be de-biased) I see no reason why one dataset would be preferred over the other. Put differently- you have no guarantees that the historical sample is more representative than the full sample.

If, on the other hand, if the historical data lends itself to de-biasing, then importance sampling might be justified if it permits the de-biasing of the whole sample as well.

Comment: I am sure the historical data is 'de-biased' I have looked up importance sampling and it appears to be just what I require. Thank you for your help.